# Can I instruct browser to run a custom javascript function before even starting a web request?

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage

I want something like this : first time my web page is loaded, I store a function `fn` in browser's local storage. From then on, whenever a request to my domain is to be made `fn` is executed before even making that request (but of course after figuring out that the request is to be made to my domain)

Is it possible?

Comment: why do you need to run javascript code before your page request is started? This is not part of any web paradigm.

Comment: High level idea is this : if required HTML is already there in the browser storage, I want to totally pass on making the request.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Yet you can use caching mechanisms for what you want to achieve. For example, use a [manifest file](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are looking for is called Application Cache. Application Cache allows you to specify a cache manifest to tell a supported browser that certain files on your site should be cached, and automatically loaded form cache the moment the user visits your site a second time. The browser will check for updates AFTER the site is loaded, so even if you update the manifest file (which is the only way to tell a browser one of the cached files changed), the browser will download the updated files in the background. Then you can choose to reload the page automatically or just let the user use the old cache until the next time they load a cached page.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

This is the ONLY way to load html/images/js or execute js before a single request is sent to your site. This also means if you design your site/app correctly, it can be used even if the user is completely offline.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store functions using any of the semi-permanent means of Javascript (local storage/cookies). You could store a function name, which you would then use to determine what function to execute. If you include the javascript file on every page on your domain, then it's possible.

This could be done quite easily by setting a cookie, or storing a value in local storage. If the value doesn't exist, it's the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope not since those functions would be the net equivalent of land-mines.  Imagine I know a bank merger is going to happen so I buy a bunch of domains that the post-merger company might have, and do something to get traffic to go there which stores one of these functions in the browser cache.  The merged bank then comes after me for domain-squatting and I hand over the domain without much of a fight.  The script I embedded now runs for any request to the bank even though I don't own the domain, so it can launch a pop-under for my phishing site only when the user actually navigates to the banks website.